# How to add an item in Tasks?

Tags: conemu

I started using ConEmu as an alternative to cmd.exe, and can't figure out [how to add an item](https://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html) in Tasks to run some oft-used commands such as "c:\myapp.exe someswitch".

I tried the following, but it only opens a new tab/console without actually running the app — or at least, it doesn't show anything:

https://s22.postimg.cc/rirsecqrl/D9209_FB9-93_E5-427_D-9_E68-4915_A1_DAA354.png

Thank you.

--

Edit: Found what it was. ConEmu simply doesn't display the command it runs if you just use "cmd.exe /k myapp.exe someswitch.

```
Clink v0.4.9 [git:2fd2c2] Copyright (c) 2012-2016 Martin Ridgers
http://mridgers.github.io/clink

c:\Temp\>
```

Maybe there's a way to tell ConEmu to display the command + switches + options.

--
Edit :

Here's what it looks like when ConEmu runs a command that returns nothing: The user can't tell that the command *did* run, but there's simply no output.

https://s22.postimg.cc/pv6f52ei9/10_AD035_B-_B079-4_D93-_A668-46435_BD7_A47_A.png

(Imgur is currently stuck at "Uploading…", hence no inline picture)

Comment: I think your description is inexact. You showed properly configured Task but it's not clear what have you tried to do further.

Comment: If you know of a better way, go ahead. The issue I still have, is that ConEmu doesn't display the command in the terminal, so in case the command returns nothing… it looks like the command was never ran. The documentation doesn't seem to say if there's a way to change this.

Comment: But I ask you what do you do. Anyway, documentation mentions that you shall check your task command from `Win+R`.

Comment: Is there no way to display the _command_ that is run by ConEmu, not just the output ?

Comment: `echo command & command`? Or what?